How to solve StreamResetException: stream was reset: NO_ERROR with a long request body
I'm using Okhttp3 to send an xml file http-Request. When I try to send a long file (several thousand lines), I'll get a StreamResetException. Otherwise it works always fine, an error occurs only with a very long xml file. My code looks as following:
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .addHeader(SENDER, Sender)
            .addHeader(NACHRICHTUUID, Uuid)
            .addHeader(SCHEMEAGENCYID, SchemeId)
            .addHeader(AUTHORIZATION, token)
            .post(RequestBody.create(xml, MediaType.get(APPLICATION_XML)))
            .build();

Response response = getHttpClient().newCall(request).execute()

private OkHttpClient getHttpClient()
    {
        if (httpClient == null)
        {
            httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .callTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        }
        return httpClient;
    }

I get the following error message:
okhttp3.internal.http2.StreamResetException: stream was reset: NO_ERROR
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.checkOutNotClosed$okhttp(Http2Stream.kt:646) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.emitFrame(Http2Stream.kt:557) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$FramingSink.write(Http2Stream.kt:532) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okio.ForwardingSink.write(ForwardingSink.kt:29) ~[okio-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange$RequestBodySink.write(Exchange.kt:218) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.kt:255) ~[okio-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.kt:185) ~[okio-2.8.0.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.RequestBody$Companion$toRequestBody$2.writeTo(RequestBody.kt:152) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.kt:59) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.kt:34) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.kt:95) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.kt:83) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt:76) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.execute(RealCall.kt:154) ~[okhttp-4.9.3.jar:na]


Code should work with any valid XML file.  Try using an online XML checker and make sure the XML is Valid.  I think the server is closing the connection so you are not getting back any response.  This is usually when the body doesn't match the content-type.  It also could be a virus checker (or firewall) detected invalid data.

I have done so and there are no errors in my xml file.

the timeouts may be too small.  How long before error occurs?  If 30 seconds, then you are just reaching a timeout and the timeouts need to be increased.

No, there is no timeout. The error occurs in just a few seconds.

You could be getting errors on the connection which would cause connection to close.  I usually from cmd.exe do a ping with long data to verify hardware. Try from cmd.exe >Ping IP (or machine name) -t -l 65500  Otherwise the connection is closing for reason I've previously mentioned or a virus checker (or firewall) is blocking the data.  Your messages are short so I do not think issue is the size of the data.
